# HREF link calls out php function

Tags: php, html

I have two files. index.php and cart.php. All my functions, connection to database, etc. are located at file cart.php. There are functions that I want to call out if user clicks on a HREF link.

my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" align="center" style="width:90%; height:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">      
    <?php cart(); ?>
    <br><br>
        <div id="sidebar" align="left" style="width:15%; height:auto; background-color:#999999; float:left;">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li><a href="#" id="all">ALL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="shirts">SHIRTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="hoodies">HOODIES</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="products" style="width:85%; height:auto; background-color:#888888; float:left;">
            <?php
            products_all();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, How can I make that a HREF link calls out a specific function(which is located in cart.php) and displays it inside a div tag(in my case, in div id="products")?

It's probably easy, I am just a beginner.

Here's my cart.php just in case.

```
<?php

session_start();


$page = 'index.php';

// ***
/*
$mysql_host = "***";
$mysql_database = "***";
$mysql_user = "***";
$mysql_password = "***";
*/

// localhost
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "cartt";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));
    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)) {
        if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]) {
            $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+='1';

        }
    }
    header('Location: '.$page); 
}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['remove']]--;
    header('Location: '.$page); 
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
    header('Location: '.$page); 
}

function products_all() {
    $get_all = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products ORDER BY id DESC');

        if (mysql_num_rows($get_all)==0) {
            echo "There are no products to display!";
        }
        else {                                      
            echo '<table width="900px" allign="center" cellpadding ="5" style="background-color:transparent;">
                  <tr align="center" valign="middle">';

                  $i = 0;

            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_all)) {

                echo '<td><img src="./cartimages/'.$get_row['id'].'.jpeg" alt=" " height="225px" align="center"><br />'.$get_row['name'].'<br />'.$get_row['description'].'<br />&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'<br /><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></td>';                

                $i++;
                if ($i == 4) {
                    echo '</tr>
                          <tr align="center" valign="middle">';
                          $i = 0;
                }


            }
        }
    }

function products_shirts() {

    $get_shirts = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products WHERE type = "shirt" ORDER BY id DESC');

        if (mysql_num_rows($get_shirts)==0) {
            echo "There are no products to display!";
        }
        else {                                      
            echo '<table width="900px" allign="center" cellpadding ="5" style="background-color:transparent;">
                  <tr align="center" valign="middle">';

                  $i = 0;

            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_shirts)) {

                echo '<td><img src="./cartimages/'.$get_row['id'].'.jpeg" alt=" " height="225px" align="center"><br />'.$get_row['name'].'<br />'.$get_row['description'].'<br />&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'<br /><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></td>';                

                $i++;
                if ($i == 4) {
                    echo '</tr>
                          <tr align="center" valign="middle">';
                          $i = 0;
                }


            }
        }
    }

function products_hoodies() {
$get_hoodies = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description, price FROM products where type = "hoodie" ORDER BY id DESC');

        if (mysql_num_rows($get_hoodies)==0) {
            echo "There are no products to display!";
        }
        else {                                      
            echo '<table width="900px" allign="center" cellpadding ="5" style="background-color:transparent;">
                  <tr align="center" valign="middle">';

                  $i = 0;

            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_hoodies)) {

                echo '<td><img src="./cartimages/'.$get_row['id'].'.jpeg" alt=" " height="225px" align="center"><br />'.$get_row['name'].'<br />'.$get_row['description'].'<br />&pound'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).'<br /><a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a></td>';                

                $i++;
                if ($i == 4) {
                    echo '</tr>
                          <tr align="center" valign="middle">';
                          $i = 0;
                }


            }
        }
    }


function paypal_items() {
    $num = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value!=0) {
            if (substr($name, 0 , 5)=='cart_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, strlen($name)-5);
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price, shipping FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                    $num++;
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number_'.$num.'" value="'.$id.'">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['name'].'">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['price'].'">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="shipping_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['shipping'].'">';
                //  echo '<input type="hidden" name="shipping2_'.$num.'" value="'.$get_row['shipping'].'">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$num.'" value="'.$value.'">';
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}

function cart() {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value>0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
                    $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                    echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ &pound;'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' = &pound;'.number_format($sub, 2).'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a> <a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a> <a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[Delete]</a><br />';
                }
            }
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
    if ($total==0) {
        echo "Your cart is empty.";
    }
    else {
        echo '<p>Total: &pound;'.number_format($total, 2).'</p>';

        ?>
        <p>
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="*************">
        <?php paypal_items(); ?>        
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
        <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but03.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
        </form>
        </p>
        <?php


    }
}

?>
```

Comment: There is nothing that would do that automatically in PHP. So the answer is pretty straight forward: You need to program it.

Comment: You should learn about ajax and then read up on a javascript framework such as jquery to make ajax simpler. A good start would be :http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/02/06/a-beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-in-your-website/

Comment: I would say somebody first needs to learn javascript before even thinking about using some framework. (*note that javascript can be replaced by any language*) @scrappedcola

Comment: Please don't just paste a gigantic chunk of code. Think about what you are trying to do a little more and post only the code that is relevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a php function to run when you do something on the client, you have to make an AJAX request that calls that function, then you insert the HTML dynamically when your AJAX request returns.

Remember that PHP only generates text that is sent over the wire as HTML,CSS,JavaScript,JSON, XML,... There is no way for PHP to interact directly with your page, it can only generate new content

Here's a basic AJAX example you could use; I'll use jQuery and some simplified PHP code

ajax.php

```
function doit() { echo "anything"; }
doit();
```

page.html

```
<a href="#" id="mylink"> Load stuff </a>
<div id="products"></div>
```

page.js

```
$("#mylink").click(function() { 
    $('#products').load("/ajax.php");
})
```

That code loads the result of `doit` in ajax.php into the div with id "products" when you click on the link with ID "page.html"

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client-side javascript AJAX. Look up and read about AJAX requests.

Once you know AJAX works, you could call cart.php?runcommand=xyz on the click button and in cart.php you could check if $_GET['runcommand'] == 'xyz' then do x. You'll find jQuery javascript library has good AJAX support.

Preferably you would not having everything in one php file, then you can just make AJAX request to different files for different purposes. In your case, listproducts.php, for example.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function showHide() {
var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
  }
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
<p><input type="button" value="Show-Hide" onclick="return showHide();" /></p>
</form>
<div id="showHideDiv" style="display:none;">hello!</div>
```

Comment: Why you voted my awnser down?

Comment: Because it is completely irrelevant to the question. How is this running a php function when you click on a link?

Comment: @JuanMendes At least it didn't suggest using some external library (*cough* jQuery) ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa Really? This answer doesn't answer the question at all, if it did, then your snarky comment would be valid. I did add a disclaimer that I used jQuery for simplified code; OP is free to work out the cross browser issues on their own if they don't want jQuery. That would be another question.